Transfer function of a Voltage-Fed PCM-controlled Push-Pull converter in CCM and DCM modes
I am designing a Voltage-Fed Push-Pull converter, and I would like to determine the system's transfer function in both CCM and DCM modes. The control will be in Peak Current Mode. I am reading through Christophe Basso's seminars, which are absolutely fascinating, but unfortunately, I don’t fully understand them. How could I model the PCM-controlled push-pull converter using PWM switch model in both CCM and DCM modes? Should I derive it somehow from the buck converter?
EDIT:
Here is the schematic:

Answer for Andy aka:
Very simple. My minimum output current is 10mA (The maximum is 1.25A). If I want to operate in CCM, a very large Lx would be needed in the circuit. The P0 output power will be 500W (at 400VDC output). I plan for the converter to operate in DCM mode below 50W, which is why the transfer function for both CCM and DCM modes is necessary.

Could you explain what PCM is in this context.

Peak Current Mode

Please add a schematic and explain why a push-pull output circuit is required to be analysed in DCM. Are you trying to emulate a flyback diode for instance?

You have mainly three options (in my personal order of preference):

Look up the transfer function from a book if your push-pull converter fits one of the canonical description of such a converter
Simulate the transfer function. For this you replace the switches with an small-signal averaged model of them, open the feedback loop and insert a frequency-dependent sinusoidal signal (something which is described in Basso's articles and books) to numerically compute the transfer function.
Derive it analytically

