How should I make the PWM switch model for a push-pull converter?
I would like to build a PWM switch model for the following voltage-fed push-pull converter (which operates in current mode) to determine its transfer function.

I can handle simple topologies like buck and boost, but I don’t know how to rearrange the push-pull circuit for the PWM switch model. There is some information on Ridley's site regarding the forward converter, but unfortunately, I can't figure out how to apply it to the push-pull converter.

Didn't you ask this same question a few days ago? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/729096/transfer-function-of-a-voltage-fed-pcm-controlled-push-pull-converter-in-ccm-and

The push-pull converter belongs to the buck-derived topologies and can be modeled as a forward converter, confirming what Edin Fific said. For illustration, I ran a comparison between a SIMPLIS simulation and the PWMCM averaged model I used in my 2021 book on transfer functions. This is the cycle-by-cycle circuit in SIMPLIS:

The external ramp is set to 33 kV/s. The correct model is obtained when including the contribution of the magnetizing current which acts as a stabilizing ramp. It is reflected in the parameters sent to the PWM switch model in current mode:

The ac response between SIMPLIS and SIMetrix is in a good agreement as seen below:

The SIMPLIS model I used here is part of my free ready-made templates which can be downloaded here. This push-pull example as many more circuits, run on the free demo version

Thank you for your response. I think I will purchase your book in the near future, as I would like to fully understand these concepts. :) I have one more question: does the model remain the same if I use a transformer without a center-tapped secondary and a bridge rectifier instead?

What matters is the square waveform at the left side of the output inductor and I believe this is the same amplitude regardless of the secondary configuration. If you are into transfer functions determination, yes, my last book - thick as a "phone book" ^_^ will keep you busy for a while!

As far as I know, the push-pull converter behaves just like a forward converter during its one half-period.
It is basically like two forward converters back-to-back with a small pause (dead-time) between them, plus the pulse width which is usually controlled by feedback.
Also, the output inductor Lx can be reduced in half because there are now twice as many pulses as compared to a forward converter.
